# How to use Json with tag: span

Tags: jquery, html, json, jsp

I have the following situation:

```
function searchProduct(cod) {

            var msg = "";
            var url = '<c:url value="/user/SeachProduct?cod="/>';
            $.getJSON(url + cod,
                    function (ajax) {
                        $.each(ajax.product, function (k, value) {
                            $("#formUser").find($('[name="product.' + k + '"]')).each(function () {
                                setElementValue(this, value, 'product.' + k);
                            });
                        });
                    });
}
```

This works if you use a form which has the tag in input:

But I do not want to use a form ... I just want to use a table and populate data within the tag:

```
<span>
<table><tr>
<td><span class="TextoTabela">${product.email}</span></td></tr></table>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to manipulate the DOM? Basic functionality of jQuery, with a working example already in your question?

Comment: I just put every attribute of my object, inside the tag "span" of my table. 

I accept any suggestion !!!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. You already have similar functionality, unless you mean to say that you have no idea at all how your current code works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your javascript to achive it :

```
function searchProduct(cod) {
    var msg = "";
    var url = '<c:url value="/user/SeachProduct?cod="/>';
    $.getJSON(url + cod, function (ajax) {
        var myTable = "<tr><td>No records</td></tr>";
        $.each(ajax.product, function (k, value) {
            myTable += '<tr><td><span class="TextoTabela">'+value+'</span></td></tr>';
        });
        $("#mytable").html(myTable);
    });
}
```

Your HTML :

```
<table id="mytable"></table>
```

Thats it , Hope it helps!

Comment: I understand your idea, Jaymin Gajjar. But it did not work. 
That's about it ... I'll study more, because in the worst case use the same tags form ...

Comment: Can you post a format of ajax.product? or what it contains ? So i can get more idea why it did not work

Answer (score 0):

```
{"contaPagar": {"@resolves-to": "contaPagar","cod": 3,"titulo": "CHEQUE","numeroTitulo": "201111-Bradesco","status": "PAGO","valor": "5999.99","valorTotal": "5999.99","mora": "0.00","multa": "0.00","dataPagamento": "10/10/2014","dataVencimento": "10/10/2014","dataEmissao": "01/10/2014","pessoa": {"cod": 7,"email": "silvio@sbt.com.br","endereco": "Rua do Silvio","bairro": "Morumbi","cidade": "São Paulo","uf": "SP","cep": "00000-000","foneCel": "(22)22222-2222","ativo": true,"nome": "Silvio Santos","nomePai": "Pai do Silvio","nomeMae": "Mae do Silvio","foneRes": "(11)1111-1111","dataCadastro": "01/10/2014","dataNasc": "01/10/1920","dataAtualizacao": "11/10/2014","cpf": "797.137.372-45"}}}
```